# SDD on /dev/sda not available after standby

Tags: kernel, suspend, ssd

I installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new Acer Travelmate P215 with Ryzen 5 Proc.
Then I added my SDD from my previous Notebook as second drive. It is recognized by the system as /dev/sda. In the installation script of the notebook seller I found a notice that it is necessary to install a kernel >= 5.15. As repo was given tuxinvader/lts-mainline. From there I installed kernel 5.18 . This is recommended because wakeup from standby and support of GPU not given by lower kernel versions.
After wakeup from standby the system does not see the /dev/sda .A reboot is necessary to connect the SSD again.

Additional hint: dmesg gives error message: Lesen des Kernelpuffers ist fehlgeschlagen: Vorgang nicht zulässig
Reading kernelbuffer failed. Operation not possible (Translation from German).

Any suggestions?

**Update to the last post:**
Actually I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
The standby issue of the SSD on /dev/sda is the same.
hdparm -s 0 /dev/sda gives following result:

```
/dev/sda: spin-up:SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 setting power-up in standby to 0 (off) SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So it seems that the SSD is set to power-off by a kernel command and does not awake after wake up of the system. There is no device /dev/sda any more. Can I risk to set the power-up in standby feature (hdparm -s 1 /dev/sda)?
The manpage gives a warning for this feature.
**Update 2:**
Found a solution in Samsung forum:
https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/computers-it/samsung-860-qvo-ssd-not-accessible-after-restart-warm-boot/td-p/1515154
Here an AHCI-driver for Windows is addressed as reason. Maybe this may be an issue for ubuntu development.

Comment: dmesg issue is cleared. Must use sudo

Answer (score 0):

SSD connected via USB? I usually have issues with newer kernels and returning from standby. Before Nouveau gpu drivers caused crash, and recently Nvidia drivers caused missing USB devices. Either don't put laptop in standby considering it barely uses any power, or downgrade to older (more stable) kernel.

Maybe tell drive not to go into standby mode?

and see if that is contributing to the issue.

```
sudo hdparm -s 0 /dev/sda
```

or try removing:
DVD drive
anything connected to USB
take out wifi module (only SSD using PCIe bus)

Check BIOS settings and disable COM, LPT ports.

Let us know if this helped.

Comment: No. SDD is connected to internal SATA controller. First and boot device is SDD on PCIe bus.

Comment: No. SDD is connected to internal SATA controller. First and boot device is SDD on PCIe bus.Standby is activated when I close the notebook. Using lower kernel version was not advised because of problems with resume from energy save states. The system which was installed was 22.04 LTS. But I had to downgrade to 20.04 LTS because some of my applications does no support 22.04. So it's a bit of dilemma.